# Do While Loop Does not Stop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I created this macro to delete rows with a `0` value on `Column 5`, starting on Row6. It should stop on the Row with an empty cell on `Column 2`.
My data has about `600 rows` only. However, after `Row 20` or so, the spreadsheet just kept waiting and I need to press `Esc` Key to stop it. When it stops, it is at the last row but it does not do the last part that is to `sum column 4`.

If I press the macro again, it works fine with the new data and adds the sum in `column 4`. (by the way, it is my first macro in excel).

```
Sub DeleteRows()
'
' DeleteRows Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

    Cells(6, 5).Select
    Do While (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) <> "")
        Do While (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5) = 0)
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Loop
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 5).Select
    Loop

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Select
    Dim cel1 As String, cel2 As String
    cel1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp).Address
    cel2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address
    ActiveCell.Value = "=sum(" & (cel1) & ":" & (cel2) & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop from the bottom up when deleting rows or you risk skipping over rows.

```
sub deleteRows()
    dim i as long
    with worksheets("Sheet1")
        for i=.cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row to 6 step -1
            if .cells(i, "E").value2 =0 then
                .cells(i, "E").entirerow.delete
            end if
        next i
        with .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup)
            .offset(1, 0).formula = "=sum(" & .parent.range(.cells(1), .cells(1).end(xlup)).address & ")"
        end with
    end with

end sub
```

1. Indent your code.
2. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
3. Define a parent worksheet reference for all cells and range calls.

Comment: It worked beautifully (fast, clean), thank you very much.

Comment: I thought I had it right the first time around but after several minutes I realized that I had to escape the nested With statement by one level with .Parent.